# Webpack 4: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, v8, webpack-dev-server

After upgrading to Webpack 4.16.3 from webpack 3.x I ran into the error below when running `npm run dev` for +/- 20 min. I get this error on a huge VueJS project. On other projects I have no errors so far. I've looked up some similar issues on Github and Stackoverflow, most of them seem related to Angular. I tried the following, but the problem seems to persist.

```
--max_old_space_size=4096
```

The one thing I did notice was that the error happens when saving a file with a faulty import or export statement.

The error log:

```
[hardsource:d5167ca7] Using 732 MB of disk space.
[hardsource:d5167ca7] Last compilation did not finish saving. Building new cache.
 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin                                                    
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6805:0x2babd20]   877537 ms: Mark-sweep 1344.1 (1396.8) -> 1342.6 (1394.9) MB, 455.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.378, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[6805:0x2babd20]   877899 ms: Mark-sweep 1342.6 (1394.9) -> 1342.6 (1394.9) MB, 362.1 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.250, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0xbd4a57041bd]
Security context: 0xeb4c809e6c9 <JSObject>
    1: byteLength(aka byteLength) [0x2eacaef7f969] [buffer.js:530] [bytecode=0x13d2a9725f69 offset=204](this=0x2dd8909822e1 <undefined>,string=0x3f1ce1e95801 <Very long string[23843934]>,encoding=0xeb4c80b1a99 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
    3: fromString(aka fromString) [0xfa9ba97d19] [buffer.js:341] [bytecode=0x13d2a9720091 offset...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8b5f80 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8b5fcc  [node]
 3: 0xab730e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xab7528 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xea5152  [node]
 6: 0xeb43c6 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 7: 0xe828af v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 8: 0xfc792f v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 9: 0xab4a44 v8::internal::String::Flatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
10: 0xac2d8f v8::String::Utf8Length() const [node]
11: 0x8ce702  [node]
12: 0xb44409  [node]
13: 0xb44f79 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
14: 0xbd4a57041bd 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My `webpack.base.conf.js`

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('./config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
var HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('resources/assets/js')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay,
  },
})

module.exports = {
  mode: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    ? 'production'
    : 'development',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: ['./resources/assets/sass/app.scss', './resources/assets/js/main.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin(),
    // You can optionally exclude items that may not be working with HardSource
    // or items with custom loaders while you are actively developing the
    // loader.
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin.ExcludeModulePlugin([
      {
        // HardSource works with mini-css-extract-plugin but due to how
        // mini-css emits assets, assets are not emitted on repeated builds with
        // mini-css and hard-source together. Ignoring the mini-css loader
        // modules, but not the other css loader modules, excludes the modules
        // that mini-css needs rebuilt to output assets every time.
        test: /mini-css-extract-plugin[\\/]dist[\\/]loader/,
      },
      {
        test: /my-loader/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'vendor'),
      },
    ])
  ],
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
        : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      clockwork: resolve('resources/assets/js'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolve('resources/assets/js'),
          resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
};
```

My `webpack.dev.conf.js`

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('./config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
// const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
// const AutoDllPlugin = require('autodll-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const portfinder = require('portfinder')

const HOST = process.env.HOST
const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)

const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: config.dev.devtool,

  // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('./config/dev.env')
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'webpack/index.html',
      inject: true
    })
  ]
})

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
      process.env.PORT = port
      // add port to devServer config
      devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port

      // Add FriendlyErrorsPlugin
      devWebpackConfig.plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsPlugin({
        compilationSuccessInfo: {
          messages: [`Your application is running here: http://${devWebpackConfig.devServer.host}:${port}`],
        },
        onErrors: config.dev.notifyOnErrors
          ? utils.createNotifierCallback()
          : undefined
      }))

      resolve(devWebpackConfig)
    }
  })
})
```

EDIT: After some digging around and with the help of the developers of Webpack we concluded that this is not an issue with Webpack. Most likely this is a memory leak caused by the sass-loader. I still haven't found a solution, but will keep this updated.

What happens with this memory leak is that when you edit the same file multiple times the dev server begins flooding your memory in small increments every time the file is saved. Node then crashes when the memory limit is reached.

Comment: there is not enough information. Post your webpack config and try to get a profile from your compilation

Comment: @PlayMa256 I've added my webpack config.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/profiling-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx Do this and post as an issue on the repository, so people can analyse it. If you could reduce to a reproducible example, it is better for them.

Your config is fine, nothing strange.

Comment: Thanks, I will open a issue.

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? Try using the latest; there were some updates to the max string length in V8 a while ago and this looks like that might be the issue here.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this.?

Comment: @NikhilMahajan Well, yes but actually no... The error disappeared while tweaking caching in Webpack. I still don't know what caused this.

Comment: Actually, I was able to resolve. In my case, it was source maps. Due large project size the source maps were throwing out of memory. I have to remove in case of production source maps to get that working again.